# Improving Greedy Algorithm for Factoring Finite Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

In Gallian’s 9th edition Contemporary Abstract Algebra, Gallian described an algorithm to express a finite Abelian group as an internal direct product of prime-power cyclic groups - of which is described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924762/fundamental-theorem-of-finite-abelian-group).

Later, Gallian mentions a way to improve the algorithm so that the internal direct product is of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}\oplus…\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$ where $n_i$ divides $n_{i-1}$. He claims that replacing step $4$ with the following procedure does the job:

> Select an element $a_i$ of maximum order $m$ such that $m\leq \frac{|G|}{|G_{i-1}|}$ and none of $a_i, a_i^2, …, a_i^{m-1}$ is in $G_{i-1}$ and define $G_i=G_{i-1}\times \langle a_i\rangle$.

Considering the post I linked, I don’t know why this would result in a factorization of $G$ already in the form I described above. The only thing that changed is that all powers of $a_i$ are being checked rather than just the powers of $a_i$ that are of the form $p^k$. Both do the same job of making sure there is no non-identity intersection between $G_1G_2\cdots G_{i-1}$ and $\langle a_i\rangle$, so why do they result in the factorization being in the desired form?